# How to get SVG node at coordinates with Batik

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have an SVG and the point (for example (x,y) = (250,112)). Is it possible with BATIK to get the node (DOM element) at the given point?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on [batik users forum](http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/SVG-elements-and-absolute-position-td2975142.html)  developed by user templth, I take no credit I just repost the solution here so It can have more exposure.

```
public Element elementAtPosition(Document doc, Point2D point) {
    UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
    DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
    BridgeContext context = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
    context.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);
    GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
    GraphicsNode rootGraphicsNode = builder.build(context, doc);

    // rootGraphicsNode can be offseted relative to coordinate system
    // that means calling this method on coordinates taken directly from the svg file might not work
    // check the bounds of rootGraphicsNode to determine where the elements actually are
    // System.out.println(rootGraphicsNode.getBounds());

    GraphicsNode graphicsNode = rootGraphicsNode.nodeHitAt(point);
    if (graphicsNode != null) {
        return context.getElement(graphicsNode);
    } else {
        // if graphicsNode is null there is no element at this position
        return null;
    }
}
```

Tested on Batik 1.9. This method returns only the topmost element on specified position. As a workaround you could remove the element and call nodeHitAt again.

Comment: What about the backward task? How to get coordinates of the particular element? Like https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class SVGMouseListener implements MouseListener {

  private final JSVGCanvas svgCanvas;

  public SVGMouseListener(JSVGCanvas jsvgCanvas) {
    this.svgCanvas = jsvgCanvas;
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // Get the BridgeContext
    BridgeContext bridgeContext = svgCanvas.getUpdateManager().getBridgeContext();

    // Get the GraphicsNode at the SVG coordinates
    GraphicsNode gvtRoot = svgCanvas.getGraphicsNode();
    GraphicsNode svgNode = gvtRoot.nodeHitAt(new Point2D.Float(e.getX(), e.getY()));

    // Handle the element
    if (svgNode != null) {
      Element element = bridgeContext.getElement(svgNode);
      if (element != null) {
        System.out.println("Clicked on element with ID: " + element.getAttribute("id"));
      }
    }

  }
```

You need to have called `svgCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGComponent.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC)`,
otherwise the `UpdateManager` of the `svgCanvas` is null.